# 13.10 won't boot after installation

Tags: boot

I have a Samsung Q30+ laptop (see http://www.cnet.com.au/samsung-q30-plus-240064143.htm), vintage 2007. I have been running Ubuntu 12 without any problems. After notification of an update to 13.10, I decided to do a clean install of 13.10 (32bit) using an ISO DVD.

I had no problems with the install but when the system rebooted (DVD ejected), all I got was a blinking cursor in the top left of a black screen. Nothing seemed to get it passed this impasse. I tried a number of clean installs of 13.10 but all ended up in the same place.

I am an ameuter at Ubuntu and haven't a clue what to try (except to wonder if it has anything to do with a new boot option). I'd hate to have to go back to Windows!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the computer is trying to boot from the newly formatted ubuntu partition? How many hard drives or partitions do you have? Try analysing the boot priority order within your bios to ensure that the computer is at least trying to boot from the right partition and that the blinking cursor is actually coming from the new install.